# Flutter - How to change the background color of awesome_notification?

Tags: flutter, push-notification, notifications, flutter-dependencies, awesome-notifications

I am using the awesome_notification plugin to show scheduled notifications in flutter. Everything works fine, but the notification is so simple-looking. It has a white background and black text. I wonder if there is a way to change the notification's background color.

Answer (score 0):

```
   NotificationChannel(
              channelGroupKey: 'basic_tests',
              channelKey: 'basic_channel',
              channelName: 'Basic notifications',
              channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
              defaultColor: Color(0xFF9D50DD),
              ledColor: Colors.white,
              importance: NotificationImportance.High
          ),
```

If you need more clarification refer the [link](https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications/example)